# How to set up networking in VirtualBox so host and other systems on host's network can access the services on my virtual instance

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I tried using bridged adapter mode but it did not work in my school's network.

I was wondering if someone could give me a simple guide on how to set up virtual networking in VirtualBox (5.1.2) that the following scenarios work:

- Both Host and Guest can access Internet
- Host and other machines on host's network can ping Guest and vice versa
- Host and other machines on host's network can access virtual instance's services for example an apache web server running on Guest and vice versa

I've been fiddling around with the various Network Adapters available in the settings for my Guest, but I'm just not able to figure it out. Anyone that can help me out here?

The host is running Windows 10 64-bit and the guest is running Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact you stated [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758838) the bridged configuration works well at home but on on your school's network, the issue might be that your school's network is using fixed IPs for your hosts or that it doesn't allow unregistered mac addresses to get dhcp replies. In such case, if you really want ping to be allowed, there is nothing you can do without violating the rules and putting the network at risk.

On the other hand, using NAT and port redirection would allow client/server communication between VMs but a more complex way.

Answer (score 0):

The default network connection in virtual box should allow communication between the host and the guest, but all other devices on the network will need static routes added to point traffic destined for the guest to be directed to your host.

Comment: Both of your statements are incorrect. The default configuration is NAT and doesn't allow communication between the host and the guest, only the opposite. Static routes won't help to overcome this issue.